# Git interactive rebase, edit particular commit without needing to use editor?

Tags: git, rebase

Currently I need to do: 
`git rebase -i f47adfa0` which show me:

```
pick 447a1cb Either left or right
pick ef35186 Introducing side effects
```

I then modify it to:

```
edit 447a1cb Either left or right
pick ef35186 Introducing side effects
```

If I would like to `edit` a particular commit (`447a1cb` in this case) is there a command I can use to invoke that state directly? Rather than having to go through the above procedure?

Comment: [`git fixup`](https://blog.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/) is very helpful alias for amending old commits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot think of a quick way to do this. Here is one way. It works regardless of how far back the commit happens to be, but note that the `rebase` will eat any merges along the way.*

```
git checkout 447a1cb
<edit stuff>
git commit --amend
git checkout -
git rebase --onto @{-1} 447a1cb
```

Note that I have used the commit hash `447a1cb` explicitly above in the first and last step; this can of course be replaced by a relative reference such as `HEAD^` as long as the same commit is referenced in both steps.

The above explained:

1. Check out the commit to be edited directly *(note: you will be in "detached HEAD" state, this means any changes here will not affect the branch you had checked out before this step, until you make that happen in step 5)*.
2. Edit what you need to edit
3. Amend the commit with the new changes
4. Check out what was previously checked out, i.e. the branch if you had one
5. Rebase the branch onto the commit checked out before (4), ignoring the commit at `HEAD^` (the first parent of the last commit, i.e. one commit back) and earlier. Using `--onto` will avoid also applying the old commit, which could lead to conflicts or an additional commit.

More info at [man git-rebase](https://gitirc.eu/git-rebase.html).

While the above method works, I would probably prefer interactive rebase most of the time.

---

* If there are merges after the commit you are editing, consider either the <s>`--preserve-merges` flag to `git rebase` (but read the *BUGS* part [man git-rebase](https://gitirc.eu/git-rebase.html))</s> `--rebase-merges` flag to `git rebase`, or instead use `git replace --edit` in combination with `git filter-branch`. More info at [man git-replace](https://gitirc.eu/git-replace.html) and [man git-filter-branch](https://gitirc.eu/git-filter-branch.html).

Comment: I believe your solution could be shortened a bit: replacing the last two lines `git checkout - && git rebase --onto @{-1} 447a1cb` with `git rebase --onto HEAD 447a1cb @{-1}`

Comment: Yes, but that would require a `git checkout` and a `git reset` as a final step, given that the starting point is a branch to be updated, would it not?

Comment: No I don't think so, according to the docs and the tests I performed, when you add an extra argument to `git rebase`, it just performs the checkout beforehand and no `git reset` is required.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can create a temporary branch and then merge it back with `rebase`:

```
 $ git checkout -b temp-branch <SHA1>
 $ git commit --amend -m 'new commit message'
 $ git checkout -
 $ git rebase @{-1}
 $ git branch -d @{-1}
```

Comment: I was about to answer something similar ;) but note that the line `git rebase @{-1}` won't work because it will replay the old commit (and could typically lead to a conflict)

Comment: I've just repeated it everything worked well. What's exactly wrong in `git rebase @{-1}`?

Comment: I've just tried this and indeed if I modify the same file that was present in the initial commit, it reports merge conflicts, while in the interactive method it would handle these automatically somehow.

Comment: The issue is that although `git commit --amend` will remove the <SHA1> commit in `temp-branch`, `git rebase @{-1}` will re-add the changes of the deleted commit! So the workflow you propose is not equivalent to `git rebase -i ...`

Comment: I'm going to dive in the docs just now to try to solve this, if you want I can recap what I find in a separated answer.

Comment: FYI it suffices to replace `git rebase @{-1}` by `git rebase --onto @{-1} <SHA1>` to skip the old commit.

Comment: Just saw @jsageryd has replied faster :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed or any other command as a temporary editor for git rebase:

```
EDITOR='sed -i 1s/pick 447a1cb/edit 447a1cb/' git rebase -i f47adfa0
```

Make it into a reusable command:

```
git config alias.edit-commit \
  '!f(){ EDITOR="sed -i 1s/pick/edit/" git rebase -i "$1"^; }; f'
```

Then:

```
git edit-commit 447a1cb
# make changes
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```